# Correct way of using forbidden word tag

Tags: hunspell

I am planning to add this tag to hunspell affix file.

```
FORBIDDENWORD z
```

But I am not sure how it will work in this case...

```
test/sz
```

The s flag is already generating a few words in this case (for e.g. tests)
Will "test" and "tests" both words will be forbidden now?

I know that the best option to use **test/z** and block the word test it self.
But I will like to know if z tag can be used along with other tags and what will be it's implications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably too late to be useful to you, but for future reference...

All affexed forms are forbidden. So e.g. `test/sz` will forbid both `test` and `tests` (assuming the `s` flag pluralizes).

The man pages clarify this:

> This flag signs forbidden word form. Because affixed forms are also forbidden, we can subtract a subset from set of the accepted affixed and compound words.

https://linux.die.net/man/4/hunspell